# Найти все чекбоксы на виджете PyQT5

Tags: pyqt5

Есть gui приложение (python3 + pyqt5).

Как получить доступ ко всем дочерним компонентам, а конкретнее – к чекбоксам, для установки их состояния? Чекбоксов множество, поэтому не хочется поименно отмечать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно кому то пригодится, вот готовое решение:

```
checkboxes = formwidget.findChildren(QCheckBox)
for item in checkboxes:
    item.setChecked(True)
```